# Android code for using google custom search API

Tags: android

Can anyone please share some java codes for getting response from google search. I am stuck over "Result=403" and "Connect failed:Network is unreachable".Please check my coding below. I'll be thankful if anyone can help me.(I have obtained API key and custom search engine id).

Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String SearchUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=AIzaSyByPqZ3jZG5KOsg7EmxSGTHhp3SIL7dyIk&cx=012845902157700116531:oqktayhycq4&q=";
    private String SearchItem = "android";
    private String SearchQuery = SearchUrl + SearchItem + "&alt=json";
    TextView searchResult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        searchResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        new JsonSearchTask().execute();
    }

    private class JsonSearchTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        String searchResultString = "";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                searchResultString = ParseStringResult (sendQuery(SearchQuery));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        searchResult.setText(searchResultString);
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    }

}
       private String sendQuery(String query) throws IOException{
           String result="";
           URL sUrl=new URL(query);
           HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) sUrl.openConnection();
           httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
           httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
           //if(httpURLConnection.getResponseCode()==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
               InputStreamReader inputStream=new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream());
               BufferedReader bufferedReader=new BufferedReader(inputStream,8192);
               String line=null;
               while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                   result+=line;
               }
                  bufferedReader.close();
         //  }
       return result;
   }
    private String ParseStringResult(String json) throws JSONException{
        String ParseResult="";

        JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(json);
        JSONObject jsonObject_responseData=jsonObject.getJSONObject("responseData");
        JSONArray jsonArray_result=jsonObject_responseData.getJSONArray("results");

        ParseResult+="Google Search for :"+SearchItem+"\n";
        ParseResult+="Number of result returned ="+jsonArray_result.length()+"\n\n";

        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray_result.length();i++){
            JSONObject jsonObject_i=jsonArray_result.getJSONObject(i);
            ParseResult+="title"+jsonObject_i.getString("title")+"\n";
            ParseResult+="content"+jsonObject_i.getString("content")+"\n";
            ParseResult+="url"+jsonObject_i.getString("url")+"\n\n";

        }
      return ParseResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to enable API key too. Did you do that ?

Comment: Yes, I have enabled it. Still Same error. Please help me out of this problem. Thanks alot.

Comment: Detail Message: Unable to resolve host "www.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname.